# RDoc not generating source files

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I'm using Rdoc 2.58 with Ruby 1.9.2p138. When I generate my rdoc files using the Darkfish format (which is the only option), I'm not getting the source code previews with it. There are no error messages, and the HTML files are being generated for all the classes.

I've tried updating the gem and reading the help files, but I'm not seeing any way to fix this problem.

Is this a known issue? What else can I try?

UPDATE:

example code:

```
class Iamaclass
    def initialize
        @name = "superclass"
    end

    def get_name
        @name
    end

    def proud?
        true
    end
end
```

Rdoc 2.5.8 outputs

```
Parsing sources...
100% [ 1/ 1]  someruby.rb                                                       

Generating Darkfish...

Files:         1
Classes:       1 (    1 undocumented)
Constants:     0 (    0 undocumented)
Modules:       0 (    0 undocumented)
Methods:       3 (    3 undocumented)
  0.00% documented

Elapsed: 0.0s
```

source code does not toggle in generated rdoc.

Rdoc 3.5.3 outputs

```
100% [ 1/ 1]  someruby.rb                                                       

Generating Darkfish format into /Users/paul/dev/alesrelated/someruby/doc...

Files:      1

Classes:    1 (1 undocumented)
Modules:    0 (0 undocumented)
Constants:  0 (0 undocumented)
Attributes: 0 (0 undocumented)
Methods:    3 (3 undocumented)

Total:      4 (4 undocumented)
  0.00% documented

Elapsed: 0.1s
```

source code does toggle in html output.

Comment: is your source code documented? (has comments etc?)

Comment: Yes, for the most part. But even with no comments of any kind, when I'm using an earlier version of Ruby (1.8.7) and a different formatter, if I click on a method name I get a popup window with source code.

Comment: can you provide a sample of this? and the message when the rdocs are generated + the code?

Comment: I actually fixed this by upgrading RDoc to 3.5.3. I will add a code example if I still can.

Comment: mmm you could provide an answer then so other people will know what to do. you'll be able to accept it after 2 days though

Comment: The problem is that my solution doesn't answer the question: why does this problem exist in 2.5.8, and can it be solved using 2.5.8?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add comments to your code, you can try using this for example:

```
# A description about this class
class Iamaclass
 # A description about this method
 def initialize
    @name = "superclass"
 end

 # Another description about some other method
 def get_name
    @name
 end

 def proud?
    true
 end
end
```

After this you can try running the rdoc command again.

Comment: Important to note that rdoc will NOT comment things for you, it just pretties up the documentation into a viewable HTML format.